# What part of rails MVC would an API call to AWS SDK go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and assuming this would go in controller but not 100% sure.

For example, say I have a front interface that request input from the user such as S3 bucket name. And I want to write code using AWS-SDK calling the API on AWS for S3. Would I write this code in controller folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, the user would input the S3 bucket name, and then submit a form. The form submission would pass the S3 bucket name parameter over to a controller action, and then the controller action would contain logic to do something with that S3 bucket name.

So yes, this would live in the controller, possibly a `create` action if you're planning on your form being a submission form.

Comment: Just to add that you don’t necessarily have to put the code in the controller itself. Sometimes people new to Rails get fixated on the MVC part, which can lead to bloated controllers. If it makes sense you can separate out operations like this into a separate class and simply initiate it from the controller.

Comment: What @rmlockerd is (rightly) pointing out; where you move the logic from the controller#create action into a class is often referred to as a "fat model" in rails. Google for `rails fat models` and you'll be able to read a lot of thinking behind whether something lives in a model or controller.